# Why do Double IPAs (aka Imperial IPAs, IIPAs) tend to be sweeter than regular IPAs?

Tags: taste, ipa

Why do Double IPAs tend to be sweeter than regular IPAs? (I personally have in mind Ninkasi's Tricerahops and Saint Archer's Double IPA.)

Comment: I don't consider them sweeter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeast can just process a certain amount of sugar inside the mash and therefore in double IPA there can be more sugar left in the beer, depending on the yeast that is used.

Comment: Do the yeast used to brew Double IPAs tend not to process as much sugar? Or are you saying that can be a choice for particular Double IPAs.

Comment: I don't know which yeast is used then, but in general you can just achieve a limited alcohol level.

Comment: The sweetness is also controlled with the cooking time of the mash, in the temperature range around 72°C, where yeast-unpocessable dextrose is formed. This sugar will stay inside the beer and give it the sweet taste, whereas the other sugars are converted to alcohol.

Answer (score 7):

I would say some are sweeter, some aren't. Brewers do kick up the mount of malt in IIPA's to get the ABV up there. This could lead to a sweeter taste depending on the malt bill and fermentation.

Answer (score 4):

To be classified as a double IPA it must have an ABV >= 7.5%.  That requires more malt/sugar.  However, the perceived sweetness can be a factor from yeast used and the Bitterness Ratio: http://www.madalchemist.com/chart_bitterness_ratio.html